# Do I need to define an enum as 'public' in its own file so it can be recognized outside its own package?

Tags: java, enums, package, visibility

I have two packages - x and y.

x contains the `Student` class and the `Grade` enum.

y contains the `Klass` class.

Why is the type `Student.Grade.C` not recognized in the `Klass` class in package y?

**Do I need to define it in its own file and make it public?**

```
package x;

enum Grade { A, B, C, D, F, INCOMPLETE };

public class Student {

// blah, blah, member variables, getters, setters, constructors    

}


package y;

public class Klass {

 // This enum type is not recognized in this package
 public static final MINIMUM_GRADE = Student.Grade.C; 

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you do have to declare that enum public. You shouldn't have to have it in its own file.

You would access just like your example `Student.Grade.C`;

You could `import Student.Grade` and just use `C` in your code.

Comment: *`"Yes, you do have to declare that enum public. You shouldn't have to have it in its own file."`* -> If I make it **`public`**, I get the error: `"The public type Grade must be defined in its own file".`

Comment: Did you put the enum definition inside of the `Grade` class? If you put it outside (like your example) you need a separate file. If you want it outside, maybe you want a separate file... Is the enum coupled closely with `Grade` (it seems to be...)?

Answer (score 5):

By not using `public`, `protected` or `private`, the Grade enum has [the default access level](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) - meaning only other classes in the same package can use it.